# Jmeter Http post special characters issue

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to login with http post using jmeter.

i have parameters like session & Authorization which hold special characters like below.

Authorization AOrSwPpS0tB6XXICp8IVE-9aGSkGeYGFxEvucSJHYYDZ.Wp-24VvrLR4.-6Y9QQo.

Session   ljvrB3JGxTpHFkrtUSyQXJSRz4E7w5uSwQmTqfWWRBA-dYRKPt58UJqPqPu

I'm not able to login. please advise me to fix this issue.

Comment: I did surfing about this issue. i got some insight. Chars: tCQlf0XNKBHzDIb1QGUwPbQgVTifztilPTz&#x2d;zHFuRLelob4OHvGmr9BZ&#x5f;fG are wrong encoded as tCQlf0XNKBHzDIb1QGUwPbQgVTifztilPTz%26%23x2d%3BzHFuRLelob4OHvGmr9BZ%26%23x5f%3BfG  Any tips to fix the special characters &, @ , # , ;

Answer (score 0):

Check "Encode?" on the parameter in the parameters table , see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group

But I think your issue is not this but the fact that you are reusing ids you got during recording that you need to make variable through Regexp extractor for example

Comment: Thank for the reply. i have tried that option. But still I'm not able to login.

here is the post data when its making.                             currentSession=byDr5pAWw2IoU8MvEB6mBa0RZmiRUlxWp%26%23x2d%3BgRPNNvlRgv2BBFBmYBSPwI%26%23x5f%3Bdi&SESSION=tDXatNKzy_GGmZ4AE4Gzv1k1_gFChHqne8sf54sC0T2wOd31Lgdif7s5Rle&CONTEXT=wtgSziM4C5x0SI%26%23x2d%3B9CmKcv2vkSeTLK5P%26%23x5f%3Bg6HqzC%26%23x5f%3B%26%23x5f%3BYTYkcqziFNcB84p79Ja&auth=+AWxdt6Y1pP7Yw4xGPcUDZapp8vO38jxwkoFz0pzzGh4F6rjbWwwn%26%23x2e%3B2JP445xq%26%23x2e%3B6JE&form_charset=UTF-

Comment: hen i do recording post looks good as the values are hard coded there.

Comment: currentSession=RBuCiVrIWKO2x2H0BbtzgyigWpm8e4q-JaV4KirSJ3exFY3BqDIShT2ilmS&CONTEXT=wtgSziM4C5x0SI-9CmKcv2vkSeTLK5P_g6HqzC__YTYkcqziFNcB84p79Ja&auth=AoM0wZM1mi5sM2KFZ1JZCf0yvs08otACymHWOKNSUk271g8AjQzo6GXl1AeBi98fu&

Comment: Yes i used the regrex expression extractor and parametrized the variable. Issue arises when posting the special characters. kindly help me.

Comment: Here is the snapshot. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlhjl40ia5x5f5k/logon%20screen.jpg)